# Errors LNK2019 and LNK2028 in VC++ Express 2008

Tags: c++, visual-c++, lnk2019

I'm trying to build a solution with 2 projects and get these error messages:

ColliderTest.obj : error LNK2028: undefined token (0A000080) "public: __thiscall Rect::Rect(int)" (??0Rect@@$$FQAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl myFunction(void)" (?myFunction@@$$FYAXXZ)

ColliderTest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Rect::Rect(int)" (??0Rect@@$$FQAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl myFunction(void)" (?myFunction@@$$FYAXXZ)

The code:

- In the project "Collider" I have these files:

Collider.h

```
#pragma once

class Rect{

    int x;
    int y;
    unsigned int w;
    unsigned int h;

public:
    Rect(int x);
};
```

Collider.cpp

```
#include "Collider.h"

Rect::Rect(int x){
    this->x = x;
}
```

- The project "ColliderTest" has a reference to the project Collider, and this file:

ColliderTest.cpp

```
#include "../app/Collider.h"

void myFunction();

void myFunction(){

    Rect rect(4);
}
```

Also, each project has a main.cpp file with an empty main() function, to avoid the complains of the compiller about the entry point.

Comment: After searching for some info on that problem, I came to the conclusion that the problem is in the reference. It might not be done right. I think this can help even more: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235590(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both projects have a main function?

That means you are building two executable.  Executables typically do not export functions.

You need one executable and one class library (dll).

BTW:  If you have an empty main function, how will you know if your program ran?

Comment: It's impossible to have an executable project, and another one to test it? I remember I did something like that with C#, so I tought it would be the same.

Comment: C# supports multiple main methods with you telling the compiler which one to use (by the class name that it's in) for a specific build.  C++ doesn't support that kind of thing directly, though something similar could probably be cobbled together with clever project/makefile configuration.

Comment: @Granjero: You may have two executables, but you would have to use Inter-Process Communication to test one using the other. I suspect that is not what you intend however.

Comment: No, I supose that the easiest way is to make a dll then :P